# Spring gateway(webflux) - oauth security - issue

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth-2.0, gateway

Spring 2.2.5.RELEASE
Spring Gateway
  - spring-cloud-starter-gateway
  - spring-cloud-security
  - spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server

SSO: keycloak 8.0.2 (docker)

I've an issue with spring gateway security configuration. In my system there are a Spring gateway and Keycloak instance behind a proxy and firewall and I would like them to communicate inside the private network. See the following [image](https://ibb.co/pZCWB5m)
for the architecture structure.

In fact in my private network I have not access to the internet because of the firewall rules.

I tried to configure spring provider using for the authorization-uri the public address of keycloak and for token-uri/jwk-set-uri/user-info-uri the private address of keycloak: this configuration doesn't work because seems that authorization-uri and user-info-uri must have the same base url.

```
 security:
oauth2:
  client:
    ...
    provider:
      myprovider:
        authorization-uri: http://sso.domain.it/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
        token-uri:http://sso.private.name/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
        jwk-set-uri: http://sso.private.name/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
        user-info-uri: http://sso.private.name/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
        user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

I get 401 and Keycloak logs this error:

```
 21:33:20,636 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-14) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=myrealm, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=x.x.x.x, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
```

If I try to set the user-info-uri with keycloak public address the authentication flow works correctly (obviously removing firewall rules).

WORKS BUT NOT OK

```
  security:
oauth2:
  client:
    ...
    provider:
      myprovider:
        authorization-uri: http://sso.domain.it/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
        token-uri: http://sso.private.name/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
        jwk-set-uri: http://sso.private.name/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
        user-info-uri: http://sso.domain.it/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
        user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when Keycloak generates JWT, it records issuer in it, in your case - accoring to **authorization-uri** hostname: **sso.domain.it**. When you later access it with **sso.private.name**, mentioned in the **user-info-uri** field - there will be no match, which in turn causes `401 Unauthorized`.
To fix the issue, you need to set up environment variable for Keyloak

```
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://sso.domain.it/auth
```

in the way you prefer - via Docker/Kubernetes environment, Keycloak startup command line etc